# Allow window.onbeforeunload when all rows with a state are removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I am working with a MVC4 project. I have an edit page where I allow users to add items to a HTML table. When items are added and not saved, I use a **window.onbeforeunload** to warn the user when trying to leave the page. Everything is working out expect the case where I only delete one item from the table, my **window.onbeforeunload = null;** triggers. I only want it to trigger when ALL items are removed.

Code examples:

```
$("#AddLinkDiv a").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../DrugArticles/EditHandledPropertiesRow/" + $("#NplPackId").val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#EditDrugArticleTable tr").last().after(data);
            $("#EditDrugArticleTable tr").last().addClass("ToBeAdded");
                window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
                };
            addDatePicker();
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
    return false;
});
```

...

```
if ($("#EditDrugArticleTable .State[Value='New']").find("tr").length == 0) {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

...

```
    $("#EditDrugArticleTable").on("click", "td.Delete a", deleteRow);
```

...

```
    function deleteRow() {
    var parentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
    var state = parentRow.find("input.State").val();
    if (state == "Existing") {

        parentRow.addClass("ToBeDeleted");
        parentRow.find("input").not("[type='hidden']").prop("disabled", true);
        parentRow.find("input.State").val("Deleted");

        $(this).toggleClass("backStage");
        $(this).attr("title", "Ångra");
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        };
    }
    else if (state == "Deleted") {

        parentRow.removeClass("ToBeDeleted");
        parentRow.find("input").prop("disabled", false);
        if (!parentRow.find("input.Procured").is(":checked")) {
            parentRow.find("input.Price").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        parentRow.find("input.State").val("Existing");

        $(this).toggleClass("backStage");
        $(this).attr("title", "Ta bort");
        if ($("#EditDrugArticleTable").prop(".State[Value='New']")) {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        }
    }
    else if (state == "New") {
        parentRow.remove();
        if ($("#EditDrugArticleTable").prop(".State[Value='New']")) {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this:
$(window).unbind("beforeunload"); - when you need to undind event

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { ... }); - or this, when you need to get it back

Be careful using this event. Opera doesn't handle onbeforeunload, or i don't know hot to do it.

---

After last comment I think it must look like this:

`function ckeckUnloadEvent() {
    if ($("#EditDrugArticleTable .State[Value='New']").find("tr").length == 0) {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
    else {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        };
    }
}`

Your function:

```
var parentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
var state = parentRow.find("input.State").val();

if (state == "Existing") {
    ...
}
else if (state == "Deleted") {
    ...
}
else if (state == "New") {
    ...
}

ckeckUnloadEvent();

return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this solution but it unfortunately has the same behavior as before (it still triggers when ONE item/row of the table is removed).

Comment: Then, i don't really understant a question. You use `$("#AddLinkDiv a").on("click", ...` to remove rows from a table?

Comment: No, I use separate JQuery for that. _See updated question._ In order for my **onbeforeunload** to trigger at the right time I need to check the state of the new rows added, which are named 'New' since they are not actually saved by the submit I have. I want to trigger **window.onbeforeunload = null;** when all rows are deleted.

Comment: Minor changes: `if ($("#EditDrugArticleTable").find("tr").hasClass("ToBeAdded")) { ...` since I needed to check for a class with css attributes that applied to the new row. But putting the event in a separate function was very smart! Thank you for the help.